# Find duplicates by property in ng-repeat and add property to them

Tags: angularjs, duplicates, underscore.js, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object defined in my controller which gets outputted in a ng-repeater. It loooks someway similar to this:

```
var _this = this;
_this.items = [
    {
        "Entityid": "300", "Name": "Lorem ipsum #1"
    },
    {
        "Entityid": "100", "Name": "Lorem ipsum #2"
    },
    {
        "Entityid": "500", "Name": "Lorem ipsum #3"
    },
    {
        "Entityid": "300", "Name": "Lorem ipsum #4"
    }
]
```

**Question: How do I iterate through this and set a "flag" on all the items that contains duplicate "Entityid"? So it looks like this:**

```
var _this = this;
_this.items = [
    {
        "Entityid": "300", "Name": "Lorem ipsum #1", "IsDuplicated": true
    },
    {
        "Entityid": "100", "Name": "Lorem ipsum #2", "IsDuplicated": false
    },
    {
        "Entityid": "500", "Name": "Lorem ipsum #3", "IsDuplicated": false
    },
    {
        "Entityid": "300", "Name": "Lorem ipsum #4", "IsDuplicated": true
    }
]
```

I have underscore included in the project if it makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through once and get counts of entity ID's and store in object, then go through again and add appropriate value for property by doing count lookup

```
var tmp={};

_this.items.forEach(function(item){
    if(!tmp[item.Entityid]){
        tmp[item.Entityid] = 0;
    }
    tmp[item.Entityid] ++; 
});

_this.items.forEach(function(item){
    item.IsDuplicated = tmp[item.Entityid] > 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use underscore's [**countBy**](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy) to county the number of items with the same id and then [**extend**](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) each item with the IsDuplicated property:

```
var counts = _.countBy(items, 'Entityid');

_.each(items, item => _.extend(item, { IsDuplicated: counts[item.Entityd] > 1}))
```

or even shorter:

```
_.each(items, item => item.IsDuplicated == (counts[item.Entityd] > 1));
```

Comment: Decided to go with the solution beneath, but will boost your answer as well. Thx